# WC_Product_Query() Only Returns Vareble Products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the following code on my WooCommerce site

```
$diet = $_POST['diet'];
    $size = $_POST['size'];

    $args = array(
        'type' => array('simple', 'variable'),
        'category' => explode(',', $size),
        'tag' => explode(',', $diet),
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'status' => 'publish',
        'limit' => -1
    );

    $query = new WC_Product_Query( $args );
    $products = $query->get_products();
```

The code only returns 13 products all variations and none of the 60+ simple products that match the criteria.

All products can be returned with using the shortcode

`[products category="regular" tag="meat,fish,vegetarian,vegan"]`

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the formatting of the `$_POST` variables as they're passed? Or maybe `print_r($args)` and show the output?

Comment: These are grabbed by JavaScript for the data attributes from the button seen below

`data-diet="meat,fish,vegetarian,vegan" data-size="regular"`

Comment: Have you tried removing type from your query? I would also try putting the variables in to your array directly rather than passing them at least to make sure things are working.

Comment: I have removed the type from the query and still saw the same results. I have also tried to specify the type as only simple and I get no results back.

I have also tried creating all 3 array's as a static version in PHP code and get the same result of only variable meals coming back.

Comment: And just to be sure... These products have ALL of the tags?

Comment: Yes, the products are loading on a page fine with the shortcode `[products category="regular" tag="meat,fish,vegetarian,vegan"]`